# How to point an arrow box based on geographical coordinates on Basemap?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to draw an arrow box to specific coordinates but it's not accurate. The head of the arrow should point to the point that is being made by scatter. how can I fix the problem?
Here is my code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
m = Basemap(projection='merc',
               llcrnrlat = 39, 
               urcrnrlat = 59,
               llcrnrlon = -10,
               urcrnrlon = 45,
               resolution='l',lat_0 = 58.9, lon_0 = 25.3,
               ax=axes)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.9)
m.drawcountries(color='blue')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.fillcontinents(color='lightgreen')

# x, y = m(51, 4, inverse=True)
# x2, y2 = m(50, 6, inverse=True)
bbox1 = dict(boxstyle='{},pad={}'.format('rarrow', 1), fc='green', ec='green', lw=5)
axes.annotate('text',xy=m(cities['LOCATION x'].iloc[0], cities['LOCATION y'].iloc[0]) , xycoords='data', rotation=20, ha='right', va='bottom', color='black',
                     xytext=(cities['LOCATION x'].iloc[0], cities['LOCATION y'].iloc[0]), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=10, weight=1000,
                    bbox=bbox1,)
m.scatter(cities['LOCATION x'].iloc[0], cities['LOCATION y'].iloc[0], latlon=True, s=200,
                  marker='o', alpha=1, zorder=2, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the width and height of the arrow from its position when initializing it?

Comment: @Bonfire no, but how to get the size of the arrow?

Comment: To tell you that, you need to show me the code where the arrow is created.

Comment: I can't tell if it is included in your code.

Comment: it is included, **bbox1** and **annotate**

Comment: @Bonfire Please check the image (updated)

Comment: I would suggest playing around with the values here. It is not a very efficient way, but I would try that. If you don't want to do that, the first thing you should find out are the dimensions of the arrow.

Comment: I think that the width of the arrow is 1 (because 'lw' is set to 1)

Comment: @Bonfire Thank you, I figured it out :), when I subtract longitude by 2 and latitud by 3 it fixes the misplaced arrow

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @Bonfire when I subtract longitude by 2 and latitude by 3 it fixes the misplaced arrow